# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when adding ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, arkit, realitykit

I've recently attempted to add a welcome screen to my AR app that works as a Home screen. When the app loads, the user can tap the button and then the app freezes, crashes and displays the code

```
 "Thread 1: "-[_0_2_2020_2.WelcomeViewController letsGo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13ec05e00"
```

- I've tried a few of the solutions available, but I haven't been able to come up with a solution. I think it has something to do with my *IBAction connection. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

  ```
   import UIKit
   import RealityKit
   import ARKit

   class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBAction func gotPressed(_ sender: Any) {let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", 
    bundle: nil)
       if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
   "ViewController") as? ViewController {
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil) /// present the view 
   controller (the one with the ARKit)!
    }    }


  }



    class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
       //delay app launch to show splash screen
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
    launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
          Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)
          // Override point for customization after application launch.
          return true
     }
   //end splash screen delay
   @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arView.session.delegate = self

    showModel()
    overlayCoachingView()
    setupARView()

    arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:))))

    }

  func showModel(){

    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal, minimumBounds:[0.7, 0.7])

    anchorEntity.scale = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]

      let entity = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "COW_ANIMATIONS")
      entity.setParent(anchorEntity)

      arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)


    }
  //Overlay coaching view "adjust iphone scan"
  func overlayCoachingView () {

    let coachingView = ARCoachingOverlayView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: arView.frame.width, height: arView.frame.height))

    coachingView.session = arView.session
    coachingView.activatesAutomatically = true
    coachingView.goal = .horizontalPlane

    view.addSubview(coachingView)

  }//end overlay


  func setupARView(){
    arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
    configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
    arView.session.run(configuration)
  }

  //object placement

  @objc
  func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let location = recognizer.location(in:arView)

    let results = arView.raycast(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)

    if let firstResult = results.first {
        let brownCowAnchor = ARAnchor(name: "COW_ANIMATIONS", transform: firstResult.worldTransform)
        arView.session.add(anchor: brownCowAnchor)
    } else {
        print("Object placement failed - couldn't find surface.")



        //cow animations
        //let robot = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "COW_ANIMATIONS")
       let brownCowAnchor = AnchorEntity()
        let blackCowAnchor = AnchorEntity()

        //anchor.children.append(robot)
        //arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

        //robot.playAnimation(robot.availableAnimations[0].repeat(duration: .infinity),
                                                      //transitionDuration: 0.5,
                                                            //startsPaused: false)

        //start cow animation


        let brownCow = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "COW_ANIMATIONS")
        let blackCow = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "Cow")

        brownCow.position.x = -1.0
        blackCow.position.x = 1.0
        brownCowAnchor.position.z = -2.0
        blackCowAnchor.position.z = -2.0
        brownCow.setParent(brownCowAnchor)
        blackCow.setParent(blackCowAnchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(brownCowAnchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(blackCowAnchor)

        let cowAnimationResource = brownCow.availableAnimations[0]
        let horseAnimationResource = blackCow.availableAnimations[0]

        brownCow.playAnimation(cowAnimationResource.repeat(duration: .infinity),
                                            transitionDuration: 1.25,
                                                  startsPaused: false)

        blackCow.playAnimation(horseAnimationResource.repeat(duration: .infinity),
                                                transitionDuration: 0.75,
                                                      startsPaused: false)

        //end cow animations
    }
  }

  func placeObject(named entityName: String, for anchor: ARAnchor)  {
    let entity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: entityName)

    entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    arView.installGestures([.rotation, .translation], for: entity)


    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
    anchorEntity.addChild(entity)
    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)


  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The button is triggering a function `letsGo` which doesn't appear anywhere on the `WelcomeViewController` you posted. Check interface builder and make sure that you've removed the old connection from the button. Should be the final tab. [image]

Comment: Note that the error says it's expecting `letsGo:` in `WelcomeViewController` rather than `ViewController`.

Comment: True. I should've been more clear. He posted WelcomeViewController's code. I'll edit and call it that